# Executing php code from frontend inorder to allow http iframe on https website

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I'm developing a new website for my company, and I would like to allow HTTP content within an iframe on HTTPS website.

I found a solution suggesting to use cURL in PHP file, however I'm facing some difficulties while trying to execute this php file. 
I'm using AngularJS in the frontend and Spring in the backend.
This is what I was trying to do so far :

iframe.html:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <uib-tabset active="active">

        <uib-tab index="1">
            <uib-tab-heading> myIframe </uib-tab-heading>
            <div class="panel-body" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
                <iframe ng-src="/components/iframes/redirect.php?url=http://www.mywebsite.com" frameborder="0" style="width: 103%;height: 800px; overflow: auto"></iframe>
            </div>
        </uib-tab>

    </uib-tabset>
   </div>
</div>
```

redirect.php:

```
<?php
 if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
 $url = $_GET['url'];
 $ch = curl_init();
 $timeout = 5;
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 echo $data;
}
?>
```

I expect the page to the display a tab with the iframe inside it, however instead of displaying the iframe, it downloads the php file.

Comment: is PHP enabled on your system? what happens if you directly type the address of target url in the browser?

Comment: It just downloads the file

Comment: Your “solution” is only half of a solution anyway. You are doing nothing more than passing the initial HTML source code of the page along. Any assets embedded into that page using relative URLs likely won’t work any more, and absolute URLs starting with `http://www.mywebsite.com` again have the problem that they are likely to get blocked …